# Expressing a point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a sum of unit vectors

Tags: geometry, vectors, analytic-geometry

I'm pretty sure that any point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be written as a sum of finitely many unit vectors (in $\mathbb{R}^n$, of course). However, I have no idea how to go about proving this.

Any ideas?

Comment: *Hint:* look up the definition of basis (of a vector space).

Comment: @AlessioPellegrini But if the OP is asking for *sums* and not linear combinations then this becomes a little less trivial.

Comment: I have this physical intuition but haven't thought much about how to make it rigorous yet: consider a bike chain of links of unit length, with total length at least the distance of your point $p$ from the origin. Fix one end of the chain to $p$, the other to the origin and let it hang due to its own weight. This gives such a sum.

Comment: You should at least assume $n>1$. In $\mathbb{R}^1$ you can only represent integer multiples of the unit vectors $1$ and $-1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume without loss of generality that your point $P$ is on the $x$-axis in the $xy$-plane. Let $L$ be perpendicular bisector of $OP$ where $O$ is the origin. Let $C$ be the circle centered at the origin of radius $\lceil P \rceil$.  Then $L\cap C=\{A,B\}$ and $P=A+B$.  Note that $A,B$ are of integer length and hence are sums of unit vectors (of the same direction). This decomposes $P$ into the sum of $2\lceil P\rceil$ unit vectors.

Comment: This construction is equivalent to finding an isosceles triangle with the given vector as one side and the other two (equal) sides having integer length.